# Como posso testar a conectividade entre equipamentos de uma rede sem usar o protocolo ICMP?

Tags: testes, redes, sistema-operacional, ping

Como posso testar a conectividade entre equipamentos de uma rede sem usar o protocolo ICMP? Eu fiz um sistema operacional simples, ele tem acesso a internet etc. Mas, não possui ping. Como posso criar um comando similar para testar a conectividade da rede?

Comment: Faça uma pesquisa sobre o protocolo SNMP, que é especificamente voltado para gerenciamento de redes.

Comment: Existem algumas alternativas possíveis.
Para a rede local você pode usar o ARP e o RARP para teste de conectividade. Já para outras redes ou para a internet, você pode usar o telnet, caso seu SO possua esse recurso. Existem muitas outras formas, mas antes de citá-las preciso que descreva melhor quais são os recursos que o seu SO possui.